# Unix Snoop Command

Tags: unix, solaris, snoop

Doing testing on a server right now.  Both the client and server are on my machine.  I am trying to snoop the packets between them but am not having any luck.  These are some variations I have tried:

```
sudo snoop host myHost and port 443 or port 8443

sudo snoop to host myHost from host myHost
```

Neither of these returns any results.  Does this suggest:

1. snoop cannot pickup packets that are between the same host
2. I am using snoop wrong
3. my client and server are doing something strange

These commands all return a lot of information (so I am assuming that it works and is configured properly)

```
sudo snoop

sudo snoop host myHost
```

Comment: Port 443 is https, if its https tgat you are trying to snoop its encrypted anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Solaris doesn't allow you to capture on the local loopback interface (lo0, in your case). For example, [this page](http://www.ethereal.com/lists/ethereal-users/200501/msg00310.html) states flatly that it can't be done on Solaris short of a kernel recompile.

So you would have to either set up the client and server on separate machines, or see if there's some way to route the traffic through your network (so that it goes through the non-loopback interface).

Comment: I created this page to verify your answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/119681/viewing-the-loopback-interface-on-solaris-10-using-snoop-or-another-tool

and to see if I can find another alternative

Comment: AFAIK, Solaris doesn't support loopback capture. It should in the future, however: http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Project+clearview/WebHome

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with snoop, but perhaps you would have better luck with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)?

Comment: Snoop is at least as capable as libpcap, if not more so.  In my experience, Solaris admins tend to prefer it.

Comment: Interesting. Good to know.

Comment: would this be able to view the loopback interface on solaris?

Comment: No, wireshark can't see the loopback either when snoop can't.
You can snoop the lookback with OpenSolaris:

# snoop -V -I lo0
Using device ipnet/lo0 (promiscuous mode)
localhost is alive
________________________________
       pcjll -> pcjll        IPNET src zone 0 dst zone 0
       pcjll -> pcjll        IP  D=127.0.0.1 S=127.0.0.1 LEN=84, ID=2656, TOS=0x0, TTL=255
       pcjll -> pcjll        ICMP Echo request (ID: 3939 Sequence number: 0)
...

Answer (score 1):

You're listening on one of the ethernet interfaces but talking over the loopback.  From the `snoop` man page:

```
    -d device       Receive packets from the network  using  the
                    interface specified by device.  Usually le0
                    or  ie0.   The  program  netstat(1M),   when
                    invoked  with  the   - i  flag, lists all the
                    interfaces that  a  machine  has.   Normally,
                    snoop  will  automatically  choose  the first
                    non-loopback interface it finds.
```

So if you want to eavesdrop on local communications, add your loopback interface using the `-d` option.

Comment: Huh, I tried that but get this error: 

`% sudo snoop -d lo0'
'snoop: cannot open "lo0": DLPI link does not exist`

Comment: maybe that is unsupported on solaris..?  See: http://serverfault.com/questions/119681/viewing-the-loopback-interface-on-solaris-10-using-snoop-or-another-tool

Answer (score -2):

1. Login to your machine as root user.
2. Run the snoop command as shown below:

   root@psp-2 # snoop -o /export/home/john/file.pcap

   Using device vnet0 (promiscuous mode)
3. Press Ctrl+C to stop the packet capture.
4. You can check the desired packet capture at the mentioned path.